# Discarded changesets in TFS 2013 are still displaying as pending merge candidates in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Since there doesn't seem to be an option to discard pending merge candidate changesets in  Visual Studio, I executed the following commands from the CLI:

```
tf merge [source] [destination] /recursive /version:[changeset]~[changeset] /discard
tf checkin
```

I then ran the following command to confirm the changeset had been removed from my merge candidate list, which did in fact remove it as expected:

```
tf merge [source] [destination] /recursive /candidate
```

The problem is when I go back to Visual Studio and execute **Branching & Merging** --> **Merge** using the same source and target branches with the **Selected changesets** option, the **Source Control Merge Wizard** still shows the changeset that I just discarded from the CLI as an available merge candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested with TFS 2013.5+VS 2013.5, but can't reproduce your scenario. In my test, when **not** perform command `tf checkin`, you'll see the changesets that just discarded from the CLI still shows in **Source Control Merge Wizard**,  if you perform command `tf checkin`, you won't see the changesets that discarded any more.

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL and still encounter the issue even after executing tf checkin

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.  Installing Update 5 did the trick and only valid merge candidates are displayed in Visual Studio now, so thank you for the info Cece!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon.  It looks like `tf merge /discard` is removing some of my unwanted merge candidates after installing Update 5, but not all.  For example: I execute `tf merge /candidate` to get a list of merge candidates, then chose one of the candidates from the list to execute `tf merge /discard` against, but the CLI returns a message stating "There are no changes to merge.", even though the merge candidate still appears in the list when running `tf merge /candidate`   Thoughts?

Comment: So I think I figured out what may be causing the issue with the merge candidates that are still appearing after running `tf merge /discard`.  I reviewed the changesets associated with the merge candidates that are still appearing after discard and they have two branch paths included with the changeset. For example: $/projectAAA/branch/alpha and $/projectBBB/branch/alpha    Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?  I tried rerunning `tf merge /discard` against the projectBBB branch, but still no luck; the associated changeset still appears as a merge candidate for $/projectAAA/branch/alpha

Comment: After further cleanup and review, it looks like some of the remaining merge candidates that are showing as partial merges (asterisk) when running `tf merge /candidate` are only associated with a single branch, but when you attempt to run `tf merge /discard` they report no pending changes.  I was able to discard many of the unwanted merge candidates, so it is much better than what it was, but I am curious as to why these others are still reported as partial merges, but no pending changes.

Comment: Not working on Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.8.5.

    - tf merge $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_10 $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_7 /recursive /candidate
    (Show changesets 369465,369463,369352)
    
    - tf merge $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_10/ $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_7/ /discard /recursive /version:C369465~C369465
    
    - tf checkin
    
    - tf merge $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_10 $/DEV_Main/DEV_624480_7 /recursive /candidate
    (Show changesets 369463,369352) THATS OK

But in VisualStudio when mergin from DEV_624480_10 to DEV_624480_7 the discarded changeset 369465 is still shown!